# How to update status field to completed after clicking on edit using ComponentEvent in lightning ,How to set values in component Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image]

```
<lightning:datatable 

                         data="{! v.PaginationList }"
                         aura:id="TskId"
                         class="slds-m-top_medium"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
                         sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"  
                         sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                         onrowaction="{!c.EditRecord}"
                         onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"
                         onsave="{! c.onSave }"

lightning js :
                      />
EditRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
     var recId = event.getParam('row').Id;

     var actionName = event.getParam('action').name;
       if ( actionName == 'Edit' ) {

        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        console.log('editRecordEvent',editRecordEvent);

        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": recId ,
         });

    var stat = event.getParam('row').Status;
     stat["Status"] = "Completed";
     component.find('TskId').submit(stat);             
        editRecordEvent.fire();

        var a = component.get('c.doInit');

        console.log('asfault',a);
    $A.enqueueAction(a);
    } }
```

Comment: Do you have more than 1 component with id `TskId`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal ,No am having only one component .

Comment: Whats the response of `console.log(component.find('TskId'));`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No response am getting.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal   its showing  -> Object is use the console.log before stat["Status"].If i use console.log after the component.find there is non response